# How can I can make the new structure compatible with the old one?

Tags: c, struct

I need to read files saved in a directory with an old structure (the first one posted below) and convert them in a new structure (the second one).

```c
struct char_file_u
{
    int iClass;
    struct char_skill_data skills[MAX_SKILLS]; 
}

struct char_fileNew_u
{
    int iClass;
    struct char_skill_data skills[MAX_SKILLS_NEW];
    char name[20];
    char authcode[7];
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with copying from the old into the new structure? Read into the old structure and then copy the old one into the new one.

Comment: Yep, just write a function to populate a new struct from the old one, make sure the new fields and extra skills are zeroed or otherwise properly initialized, and write the new struct into a new file. There's no magic.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What does the conversion code look like and what part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

You can developp a new function that has to take your **struct char_file_u** and add the fields in your **struct char_fileNew_u**.
The only tricky point is that you have to be careful with the values of MAX_SKILLS and MAX_SKILLS_NEW, that can be different.

Comment: MAX_SKILLS is 255 and MAX_SKILLS_NEW is 500

Comment: So you won't have any problem, just make a strcpy() or strncpy() to be sure to copy what you want

Comment: Should it be `memcpy` instead?

Comment: yeah, that would be a better choice